# Use javascript to open multiple windows and submit multiple requests on one button click

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML file:

```js
function runBatch() {
      
    document.form2.w_yyyymm.value=document.form1.w_yyyymm.value;
    window.open('', 'TheWindow2')
    document.form2.submit();
               
    document.form3.w_yyyymm.value=document.form1.w_yyyymm.value;
    window.open('', 'TheWindow3')
    document.form3.submit();

    document.form4.w_yyyymm.value=document.form1.w_yyyymm.value;
    window.open('', 'TheWindow4')
    document.form4.submit();
}
```

```html
    <form name="form2" method="post" action="reportm02.do" ><input name="w_yyyymm" type="hidden" >
    <input name="method" value="view" type="hidden" >
    <input name="w_goods_id" value="9999" type="hidden" >
    </form>
    <form name="form3" method="post" action="reportm02.do" ><input name="w_yyyymm" type="hidden" >
    <input name="method" value="view" type="hidden" >
    <input name="w_goods_id" value="TX" type="hidden" >
    </form>
    <form name="form4" method="post" action="reportm02.do" ><input name="w_yyyymm" type="hidden" >
    <input name="method" value="view" type="hidden" >
    <input name="w_goods_id" value="TE" type="hidden" >
    </form>

    <input type="button" name="Submit3" value="run batch" onClick="runBatch();" >
```

Either Form submit will get a xls file , So I want to get all xls files on click one button. I try ajax but all fail~ How can I do? Thank you !!

```js
function ajaxSubmit(form)
{
    var f = form; 
    var postData = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < f.elements.length; i++) { 
        postData.push(f.elements[i].name + "=" + f.elements[i].value); 
    } 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("POST", "reportm02.do", true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(postData.join("&")); 
}

function runBatch() {
    
    ajaxSubmit(document.form2);
    ajaxSubmit(document.form3);
    ajaxSubmit(document.form4); 
}
```

.. But no xls file download to client side.

I also try the following code but still not work:

```js
// Download a file form a url.
function saveFile(url) {
  // Get file name from url.
  var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
    a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
    a.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    delete a;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: `I try ajax` - did you? where?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI - what are you talking about?

Comment: Opening multiple windows from one click is exactly what popup blockers were created to prevent. (But anyway...are you saying you want to display several different xls files each in their own window? Maybe instead you could make one request that returns one xls file containing mutliple worksheets.)

Comment: @nnnnnn to update the server side code to return one xls that contain multiple worksheets is a huge work , Actually I have to open 32 windows and download 32 xls files on client,  I want to get the easiest way to finish this task.

Comment: @user871221 - right ... put that code in the question where it's readable :p

Comment: no browser will allow to open 32 seperate windows... I would implement 32 buttons each to open a different window.

Comment: @jackjop If I can get 32 xls files without open 32 separate windows.  It's a better solution. If 32 windows is not allowed. I can use 2 buttons , 1 for 16 xls and another for rest 16 xls.

Comment: change `void ajaxSubmit` -> `function ajaxSubmit` then try ajax again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the following code:

http://danml.com/download.html

And include the download.js from it as following:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" src="js/download.js"></script>
    <Script language="JavaScript">


        function saveFile(url,filename) {
            //
              // Get file name from url.
              //var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
            var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
            x.open("GET", url, true);
            x.responseType = 'blob';
            x.onload=function(e){download(x.response, filename, "text/plain" ); }
            x.send();
            }

        function runBatch() {
            if (!date_check_yyyymm(document.form1.w_yyyymm, "申報年月")) {              
                return false;
            }


           saveFile("ReportMIB.do?method=view&w_yyyymm="+document.form1.w_yyyymm.value+"&w_goods_id=9999","880103_"+document.form1.w_yyyymm.value+"_9999.xls" )
           saveFile("ReportMIB.do?method=view&w_yyyymm="+document.form1.w_yyyymm.value+"&w_goods_id=TX","880103_"+document.form1.w_yyyymm.value+"_TX.xls" )
           saveFile("ReportMIB.do?method=view&w_yyyymm="+document.form1.w_yyyymm.value+"&w_goods_id=TE","880103_"+document.form1.w_yyyymm.value+"_TE.xls" )
           .....

            }

    </script>
```

This will work on the Chrome browser but IE and firefox.